# ADB Reverse Port and Socket Communication

Tags: java, android, sockets, adb

I have a Java desktop program which runs Server Socket and a mobile app which runs Socket (Client Socket). I am communicating between the two programs through USB Connection over a TCP port through ADB.

I am sending messages from java desktop program to mobile application and vice versa.

The problem is that every thing is working fine on most of the mobile devices while it is not working only on some Samsung Tabs (one of them is Samsung Tab A model number T585). The problem cycle is that the Java desktop program is able to send the message to mobile app but in return mobile app is not able to respond over socket. I have checked the windows firewall as well and its turned off.

I have got three of the same model tabs and all of them have this kind of issue. I wonder is there any security feature in the Samsung Tabs or if someone knows is there anything/option I need to enable on mobile device/ tab to solve this issue.

Comment: `I am communicating between the two programs through USB Connection over a TCP port through ADB.`. I wonder how that would go. Or why you want to do such. And why dont you just use a wifi connection?

Comment: For the rest you should of course post your code and exceptions from the logcat.